# clone a git repo from google cloud platform

Tags: git, ssh-keys

1) i've created a repo by the web console

2) i've created the ssh keys by putty keygen (RSA 2048bit)

3) private key saved in ./ssh

4) public key pasted on the dedicated section of the GCP (and the key has been correctly accepted)

when try to access the repo (clone) by `git clone` i get this message:

```
git clone ssh://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/gcp-team-blue/r/test
Cloning into 'test'...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com@source.developers.google.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

pay attention that if i clone the repo by the gcloud utility i can clone it successfully.

Are there other security options that have i set other than ssh keys?

Comment: Have you follow all the steps here ? https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloning-repositories

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have created an ssh key for a user and trying to use another user for the git clone

For example:
When you first create the GCP VM it will create two users

- Normal **sudo** user [ex. foo]
- Root user

But when you try to git clone you will try to use `sudo` by default as the normal user doesn't have enough privileges to make create the directory for the git repo

But the Git service has the normal user [public ssh key]

So the solutions:

- Create a root user ssh key instead and use it
- Give the normal user enough permissions to create the dir